# Multilingual Text Calculator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, calculator

I'm trying to put together a Multilingual Text Calculator using just plain Javascript (not JQuery) as this is to help with revision on a past paper for uni. I've had a good go at it and created a version that does work based on two languages - English and French, however not without its flaws.

How would I go about creating a two dimensional array for each language? So for example if I wanted to do:

```
myEnglishArray = ["one", 1];
```

or

```
myEnglishArray = ["one", "1"];
```

I don't even know if thats correct or not but basically I need to go from 1 to 10 in English and the same with french and map each number in textual sense (i.e. "one") to the number in integer sense. I could of course convert a number within a string (i.e "1") using parseInt();

Any help would be great here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dictionary = 
    [["one", "uno"],
     ["two", "dos"],
     ["three", "tres"]];

dictionary[0][0];  //"one"
dictionary[0][1];  //"uno"
```

Here you just have to create **1 variable** to contain **3 information** at a time (number, English, Spanish). And also, you can easily add more languages after Spanish too!

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/5fhTw/

Comment: Thats all great info, cheers guys! I'm still having a slight issue with matching up whats in the input field with a value in the array coz the calculator needs to take input field 1 and input field 2 and add them together to create the result in input field 3.

My example would match input field 1 which could be "one" with a value in the array and then also convert this into the integer value which would also be part of the array. If i'm not making much sense then go with the original answer of

    ["one", "un", "uno", 1]

and so on....

Comment: I should also point out that the calculator will know which language it is based on which is chosen from a radio button group.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it like this:

```
var myArray = {
    "english": { "one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3, "four": 4, ... },
    "spanish": { "uno": 1, "dos": 2, "tres": 3, "quattro": 4, ... },
    ...
};
```

That way you can access each array by name:

```
console.log(myArray.english["one"]);  // 1
console.log(myArray.spanish["uno"]);  // 1
```

And cycle through the numbers using *for*:

```
for (var num in myArray.spanish) {
    console.log(num + " = " + myArray.spanish[num]);   // "uno" = 1, etc
}
```

Comment: I would do it this way, but I would switch the key and value. make the key the number, and the value the localized string. That is how I would do it. That way you can say myArray.english[1] to get "one".

Comment: Nice answer, except that I agree with @aaronfrost that the keys and values should be reversed.  However, it's worth noting that your final loop to cycle through the numbers doesn't guarantee any particular order, as [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) describes.  It's quite possible to log "dos = 2" before "uno = 1," for example.

Comment: @aaronfrost That's actually how I wrote it at first, but changed it after re-reading the Op's question.  It seems the requirement is to look up the number based on the localized string.

Comment: Thank you for the help there dude! Appreciated!